# Which of Steve Perry's novels prominently feature the "Siblings of the Shroud"?

Tags: steve-perry, matador-series, the-97th-step

I know there is [a list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Perry_%28author%29#The_Matador_series) of the books in the "Matador series", but I'm primarily interested in the society/pseudo-religion "The Siblings of the Shroud" explored mainly in "The 97th Step". Has this group appeared as anything more than cameos in any of his other books?

Comment: The [TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MatadorSeries) has a summary that may help if you're familiar with the universe. A book that will definitely interest you when and if it comes out is *The Siblings of the Shroud*, [currently in planning](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=135789).

Comment: Indeed, I am very much looking forward to that one - it's what prompted the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Siblings of the Shroud are mostly in **The 97th Step**. They are also in **The Man Who Never Missed** but less prominently.

Eventually there will be a novel entitled "The Siblings of the Shroud".

Comment: Steve - thanks for joining us, and for the answer!

Comment: Welcome to Literature.StackExchange!